# Differentiating with respect to the limits of an integral

Tags: calculus

I have the following. I would appreciate seeing how to go from line one to line two. I'm not familiar with differentiating with respect to limits. 
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^bf_{M_t, W_t}(x, y)\,dy\,dx &= \int_{2a - b}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2t}}\,du \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{-\infty}^{b}f_{M_t, W_t}(a, y)\,dy &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(2a - b)^2}{2t}}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus could help.

Answer (score 0):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^{\infty} f(u) \, du = - f(x) \tag{1}$$

for any continuous $f$ such that the integral is well-defined. Setting $$f(u) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{u^2}{2t} \right) \qquad g(a) := 2a-b$$ it follows from the chain rule that

$$\begin{align*} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{2a-b}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{-u^2}{2t} \right) \, du &= \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{g(a)} f(u) \, du \\ &= \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial c} \int_c^{\infty} f(u) \, du \right) \bigg|_{c=g(a)} \cdot g'(a) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} - f(g(a)) \cdot 2 \\ &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{(2a-b)^2}{2t} \right). \end{align*}$$